# Addition of multiple columns from 2 different dataframe based on 2 primary columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to do addition of columns from 2 dfs on 3 columns based on col1 and col2

df1:

```
 col1   col2   col3  col4  col5
 aaa    2020   12.3  6.7    8.0 
 bbb    2019   3.4   9.0    7.8
 ccc    2020   6.7   1.2    5.5
```

df2:

```
 col1    col2   col3   col4   col5
 aaa     2020   2.3    0.9    4.7 
 bbb     2019   1.1    1.4    9.8
 ccc     2020   2.5    8.9    2.2
```

Result df1(col3) + df2(col3), df1(col4) + df2(col4) etc

```
col1   col2  col3   ..........
aaa    2020  14.6
bbb    2019  4.5
ccc    2020  9.2
```

Code so far:

```
df = pd.concat((df1,df2)).groupby(['col1','col2'],as_index=False).sum()
```

But I'm getting 2 values for same combination

Comment: Your code works fine. Else; try `df1.set_index(['col1', 'col2']).add(df2.set_index(['col1', 'col2'])).reset_index()`

Comment: No its not working, i'm getting 2 rows for each combination

Comment: and for the solution you provided i'm getting NaN for all integer columns

Comment: Well, it works with your provided example, so please be sure to provide a fully reproducible example (as `DataFrame` constructors) and ensure that it triggers what you describe.

Comment: It is happening because of the index I believe. If I concat and then read the CSV again and do a groupby it is working, but directly from Dataframe it is not taking

Answer (score 1):

you can merge two df on col1 then you will get all the columns in one resultant df.then you can do this thing
'''df1(col3) + df2(col3), df1(col4) + df2(col4)'''    easily.